# lightning:inputField with a checkbox field type doesn't work when clicking the box unless label is clicked,

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform

On lightning:recordEditForm, lightning:inputField with a checkbox field type doesn't work when clicking the box unless label is clicked, this is occuring when Winter 20 is released. This is working fine during Spring '19

```
<lightning:recordEditForm
            onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
            onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
            onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
            recordId="{!v.recordId}"
            objectApiName="Case_Extension__c">

            <lightning:messages />

            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Case_Plan__c"/> <!-- field is checkbox-->
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
            </div>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue you are facing. Can you paste your code as well in your question?

Comment: I have updated the description. its just pulling the field on the object with a checkbox data type.

Comment: @sanketkumar this is occuring when using console apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too facing this issue. Hide the inputfield label and use your own label like below. I hope this will fix your issue.

```
<span class="slds-form-element__label">Case Plan</span>
<lightning:inputField fieldName="Case_Plan__c" variant="label-hidden"/>
```